# Which processes are not needed for boot?

Tags: boot, systemd, xubuntu

The xUbuntu boot takes 3m compared 1m30s Win 7 or SliTaz 20s (uncomparable) 2m Mac OS X (Hackintosh)

My Laptop has a Celeron 64bit CPU 4 gigs of RAM and a old Nvidia Card from late 2009

 6400 RPM hard drive (i think) 500 GBs

```
     21.590s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      8.665s systemd-udev-settle.service
      7.912s gpu-manager.service
      5.891s ModemManager.service
      5.099s dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6d3e8de2\x2d2956\x2d4bfb\x2db65d\x2dbb534f2
      5.027s NetworkManager.service
      4.532s accounts-daemon.service
      3.909s binfmt-support.service
      3.551s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      3.495s rsyslog.service
      3.488s systemd-user-sessions.service
      3.488s grub-common.service
      3.484s avahi-daemon.service
      3.481s ondemand.service
      3.475s thermald.service
      3.071s systemd-logind.service
      3.053s lm-sensors.service
      3.039s apport.service
      3.035s bluetooth.service
      3.031s speech-dispatcher.service
      3.027s pppd-dns.service
      3.026s irqbalance.service
      1.433s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.391s apparmor.service
      1.264s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.139s colord.service
      1.010s plymouth-read-write.service
       846ms systemd-journald.service
       845ms systemd-setup-dgram-qlen.service
       843ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       839ms polkitd.service
       783ms upower.service
       777ms resolvconf.service
       635ms dev-hugepages.mount
       634ms dev-mqueue.mount
       548ms systemd-udevd.service
       531ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       526ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       517ms wpa_supplicant.service
       496ms alsa-restore.service
       475ms dbus.service
       393ms udisks2.service
       373ms systemd-sysctl.service
       331ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       306ms console-setup.service
       285ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       282ms systemd-vconsole-setup.service
       281ms ifup-wait-all-auto.service
       271ms systemd-fsck-root.service
       261ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill2.service
       261ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       240ms plymouth-start.service
       237ms lightdm.service
       222ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill0.service
       218ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill1.service
       177ms networking.service
       170ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       163ms ufw.service
       145ms kerneloops.service
       134ms rtkit-daemon.service
       134ms preload.service
       110ms udev-finish.service
        98ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
        86ms user@1000.service
        75ms systemd-random-seed.service
        73ms dns-clean.service
        61ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        49ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        27ms hddtemp.service
        21ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        13ms rc-local.service
         7ms ureadahead-stop.service
         6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         3ms dev-sda5.swap
         3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

My question which of these processes are not needed so i can boot faster.
No I am not making a server,just normal PC usage.

Comment: The network applet (WiFi) takes allot of time, is this normal?

Comment: where/how did you find this nice and useful output about boot performance? Thankyou (sorry I can't help)

Comment: +lese "systemd-analyze blame" just do that and it should print out all of it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This information is not enough to make any useful advice. The problem is that while `systemd-analyze blame` outlines the services which took the most time to start up, it does not say:

1. whether the boot process really *waited* for that unit to activate (start), or did it take place *in background*;
2. whether the user can *voluntarily disable* that unit, or is it *required* by something else.

The first question is answerred by `systemd-analyze critical-chain` (or, in complex cases, by `systemd-analyze plot`). The second question is answerred by `systemctl list-dependencies default.target`.

Hence it'd be great if you provided outputs of those commands (except `plot`, which outputs an SVG file and is not necessary in most cases).

---

However, you could try disabling (with `systemctl disable`) `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` and `remote-fs.target` (the latter sometimes pulls in the former). The point is, you almost certainly do not need the network to be up *before* you can login, and can tolerate the network starting up in background.

Comment: Thnx I will try it as soon as possible